# Is Oracle Java KeyStore implementation thread-safe?

Tags: java

I'm looking to implement a multi-threaded SSL client that uses client certificate authentication, so I need to provide a KeyStore to the SSLContext. I need to do this on multiple threads. Is it safe to use one instance of the KeyStore? I won't modify the keystore myself, and I'm assuming that the SSL implementation won't need to either, so the object should be effectively immutable.

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In general, JCA services are not thread-safe, and `KeyStoreSpi` doesn't impose any thread-safety requirements on implementers. However, if your key store is effectively immutable, *and* you ensure that its initialized state is visible to all threads, there is no problem. For example, store the `KeyStore` in a `volatile` variable, or load it from a class initializer (which can be tricky because of exception handling).

Comment: Having your keystore to be immutable would require you to not implement methods such as `KeyStoreSpi#engineSetCertificateEntry` , and you would have to report an `KeyStoreException` instead. That's allowable, but something to keep in mind.